# Using an AVR timer to generate a 38 kHz signal

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, timer, delay

I need a 13 microseconds delay for transmitting IR at a 38 kHz carrier wave. My chip ([ATtiny84](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY84.aspx)) is running at 8 MHz. I cannot figure out what's the problem is in my code:

```
void send(long microsecs)
{
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00); // Enable Timer 0 - No prescale

    while (microsecs > 0)
    {
        // 38 kHz is about 13 microseconds high and 13 microseconds low
        PORTB |= (1 << PB2); // 3 µs
        TCNT0 = 0;
        while (TCNT0 < 104);

        PORTB &= ~(1 << PB2);   // 3 µs
        TCNT0 = 0;
        while (TCNT0 < 104);

        // So 26 microseconds altogether
        microsecs -= 26;
    }
}
```

The delay (104 clock cycles) sums up to 13 microseconds @8 MHz and the **while** loop should hang up the code for the required time period, but it's not working.

**But**

When I replace this:

```
   TCNT0 = 0;
   while (TCNT0 < 104);
```

by this:

```
_delay_us(13);
```

everything works fine.

If I'm doing something wrong, please point out.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The output is always high/low/tri-state? What? Also, these timing things are best done with timers. Google for "AVR timer tutorial" or similar. As it is far more accurate way than timing it with delays, and also ables you do execute any other code while timming.

Comment: It seems that the code is stuck at <while(TCNT0 < 104);>

Comment: Is the watchdog enabled????

Comment: No it's disabled

Comment: here's the ultimate resource for all things related to AVR timers, http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-newbies-guide-avr-timers?page=all

Comment: Can you add that part of your code when you are calling this function?

Comment: And, why do you think it stucks in the `while(TCNT0 < 104);`? Also, how do you decide/check if it is working properly or not? And how much frequency error is permitted?

Comment: Have you set  CLKPR = 0x80; CLKPR = 0x00;? these 2 CLKPR instructions have to be run together in order and must not be optimized

Comment: @Oka - Why would he need to set the system clock prescaler?

Comment: @BenceKaulics, from the datasheet http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8006.pdf page 32: "The device is shipped with the CKDIV8 Fuse programmed". It is mean that CLKPS bits are reset to
“0011” ~ clock division factor is 8. If we desire the clock division factor 1, we need to set CLKPS to "0000"

Comment: @Oka - You are right, the value of CKDIV8 Fuse should be checked. But wouldn't it be easier to change the fuse itself, rather than writing CLKPR from code? CLKPR is used to change clock-frequency dinamically, to decrease power consumption when the requirement for processing power is low.

Comment: @BenceKaulics, setting CKDIV8 or CLKPR give same result, no problem which method is choosen

Comment: The requirement is that the new value for CLKPR is written within 4 cycles, and as you said it must not be optimized. So changing the fuse maybe a little safer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating PB2, you set it high in the 1st delay and then you set it high again in the second delay, switch from PORTB |= (1 << PB2); to PORTB &= ~(1 << PB2); in one of the delays

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. Just a problem while copying from the editor to here. I was using PORTB &= ~(1 << PB2);